# Running online algorithms only on specific node and edge types in Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

I am trying to execute the `.update()` method on specific node and edge types during a trigger execution. The `.update()` method currently accepts the following parameters: `(createdVertices, createdEdges, updatedVertices, updatedEdges, deletedVertices, deletedEdges)`. It doesn't allow me to run the update on a projection and I am trying to find a workaround.

Here's a sample trigger for online community detection that I am using:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sample_trigger BEFORE COMMIT
EXECUTE CALL community_detection_online.update(createdVertices, createdEdges, updatedVertices, updatedEdges, deletedVertices, deletedEdges) YIELD *;
```

By default, the `update` method would operate on any vertex and edge supplied by the trigger, but I want to restrict the online update to propagate only across specific vertex and edge types.

One possible solution I considered was to allow conditional triggers based on types, but it appears that Memgraph doesn't currently support this feature.

How can I filter `createdVertices`, `createdEdges`, `updatedVertices`, `updatedEdges`, `deletedVertices`, and `deletedEdges` based on their types before they are passed to the `.update()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also run `.update()` on projections. You can set a subgraph as the first parameter for every procedure, including the `community_detection_online.update`. You would have to use `MATCH` to match the specific types you want and project it as a subgraph, something like this:

```
MATCH p=(n:SpecificLabel)-[r:REL_TYPE]->(m:SpecificLabel)
WITH project(p) AS subgraph
```

You would then add that subgraph as a first parameter when calling a certain procedure. In this case, it would be:

```
CALL community_detection_online.update(**subgraph**, createdVertices, createdEdges, updatedVertices, updatedEdges, deletedVertices, deletedEdges)
```